# correctly adjust the outer div when the inner div is deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say currently I have an outer div containing which contains 5 inner divs. And the outer div has a max-width and therefore it only contains at most 4 divs horizontally.
E.g: 
|d1 d2 d3 d4|
|d5

I also make a 'close' button on the inner div, so if I close one, the div would be deleted.

HERE IS THE PROBLEM:
If I delete d4, sometimes the outer div would display 
|d1 d2 d3 d5|, THIS IS WHAT I WANT
but sometimes the outer div's width shrinks a little bit and displays
|d1 d2 d3   |
|d5         |

Does anyone know why is it like this?

Comment: Sorry, the example would be |d1 d2 d3 d5|   but sometimes it gives me |d1 d2 d3  | and d5 stays at the second row.

Comment: This would be greatly aided by a snippet, if you are able.

Comment: @Kai-- I think you should have the ability to go back and edit your post-- that would be better than making comments with revisions to the question.

Comment: any fiddle to showcase your problem?

Comment: so your issue is kind of volatile? well I hate volatile or random issue.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the reply, I couldn't find the edit option. Unfortunately I also don't have code snippet as this is work related and it is quite complex to make a code snippet on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Add a min-width attribute on the outer div to prevent it from shrinking further than you want it to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, if I make a min-width, then the first time I add div1, the outer div would be |d1            |, having a lot of white space.

Comment: I know you said don't have the snippet but can you at least try recreating the html parts?